# How to Run a Task in swift on a particular date-time in background either application is on or off

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process, uilocalnotification

I am working on alarm application, i need to schedule alarm on specific time, I use `scheduleLocalNotification` for scheduling alarms and it's working fine as i want. **BUT** I need to run to a request to my API server before triggering alarm. In that request I want to check some parameters returning from API server, If that satisfies some condition.

If any one have a method that run on a particular date - time in swift 
Please help me for that

```
 func addAlarm (newAlarm: Alarm) {
    // Create persistent dictionary of data
    var alarmDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ALARMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary()
    // Copy alarm object into persistent data
    alarmDictionary[newAlarm.UUID] = newAlarm.toDictionary()
    // Save or overwrite data
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(alarmDictionary, forKey: ALARMS_KEY)

    scheduleNotification(newAlarm, category: "ALARM_CATEGORY")
    scheduleNotification(newAlarm, category: "FOLLOWUP_CATEGORY")

}

    /* NOTIFICATION FUNCTIONS */
func scheduleNotification (alarm: Alarm, category: String) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = category
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    switch category {
    case "ALARM_CATEGORY":
        notification.userInfo   = ["UUID": alarm.UUID]
        notification.alertBody  = "Time to wake up!"
        notification.fireDate   = alarm.wakeup
        notification.timeZone   = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        notification.soundName  = "loud_alarm.caf"
        break
    case "FOLLOWUP_CATEGORY":
        notification.userInfo   = ["UUID": alarm.followupID]
        notification.alertBody  = "Did you arrive yet?"
        notification.fireDate   = alarm.arrival
        notification.timeZone   = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        notification.soundName  = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        break
    default:
        print("ERROR SCHEDULING NOTIFICATION")
        return
    }
    print("Notification=\(notification)")
    // For debugging purposes
    if alarm.isActive {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately local notifications cannot be silent, only remote notifications. My advice to you would be to implement a notification facility on your server so that the user tells the server when they want their alarm to be and the server runs a method at that time, performs the checks you want then if they pass sends a remote notification to the device triggering the alarm.

Comment: @JacobKing  Thanks for Your Advise let me wait a while,
Actually i want a function which is run in the background on a given time period. if some one has any idea for that i'll wait for a while. if i didn't get any capable answer then i'll implement it on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waking up an app through a local notification is not possible, this is available only for remote notifications. According to the [Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1):

> When a **remote** notification arrives, the system handles user
>   interactions normally when the app is in the background. It also
>   delivers the notification payload to the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method of the app delegate in iOS and tvOS

But there is still a catch; even then it is not guaranteed that the app will be launched since, according to `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):

> However, the system does **not** automatically launch your app **if the user
>   has force-quit it**. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app
>   or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app
>   automatically again.

I don't think there is a guaranteed way to schedule a block for execution in some later moment, independently from the state of the app at that time. Depending on your specific requirements and frequency, you could perhaps register for the `fetch` background mode and implement `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` to [opportunistically fetch and validate server data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). Last note: make sure that you are a responsible background app (from my experience Apple takes this requirement seriously)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it completely means that there is no way to wake up an application

Comment: @APKAPPS It means that there is no guaranteed way to do so, for an arbitrary amount of time